# Python Pandas Multi Index Division

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

```py
foo bar baz
a   x    20
    y    40
    z    60
b  x     20
   y     100
   z     50
```

I have the above in a multi index data frame, and i want to divide the x in a by the x in b. i've tried

```py
 df.groupby(level = ['foo', 'bar']).divide('baz'))
```

which was recommended on another Stack thread, and it doesn't work. Not sure how to get it to effectively be a new dataframe where we have

```py
bar  a/b
x    1
y    0.4
z    1.2
```

Comment: `df.xs("a").div(df.xs("b"))`

Comment: This looks promising, I'm have some rows in A that do not exist in B and gave me a divide by zero error. Is there a way to add in an if statement to this function to skip ones that do not match? I'm downloading the data from an online repo so unable to check in advance which rows don't match to hard code them.

Comment: It ought to give NaN's, not divide by 0 (yeah I tried). This signals lack of representative example. If you share such, maybe someone helps.

Comment: Agree with @Either that examples are needed. Also please check if there is any zero in your data.